# How many different groups are referenced in the letter to Sardis?

Tags: revelation

My question is about Revelation 3:4-5. Are there three groups of Sardinian Christians being referenced here?

> (4) But you have a few individuals in Sardis who have not stained
>   their clothes, and they will walk with me dressed in white, because
>   they are worthy. (5) The one who conquers will be dressed like them in
>   white clothing, and I will never erase his name from the book of life,
>   but will declare his name before my Father and before his angels.
>   (NET)

- *Group A*: Those “who have not stained their clothes” and “who **are** worthy”
- *Group B*: Those who conquer and “**will** be dressed like **them** in white clothing”

  - (v3:5 literal Greek) “the overcoming thus will be in garments white...”  (no “**them**”)
- *Group C*: As the text goes on to say “...I will never erase his name from the book of life”, is there by implication a group-C who are not-worthy and failed-to-overcome and are therefore subject to erasure from the book of life?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revelation's church of Sardis should be seen as part of a progression that develops the "Remnant" theme - a dichotomy of two groups, the unfaithful vs the faithful remnant.

- **Pergamum** (Rev 2:12-17) two classes of people are described: those who have not renounced their faith (v 13, 14), and those who hold to the teachings of Balaam and the Nicolaitans.  The faithful overcomers are offered three rewards: *hidden manna, *a white stone, *a new name known only by receiver.
- **Thyatira** (Rev 2:18-29) two classes of people are further developed: Those who follow Jezebel and her idolatry, vs the remnant (v24, λοιποί loipoi) who do not follow Jezabel.  The faithful overcomers are offered four rewards: *authority over nations, *the morning star, *to rule with iron sceptre, *to dash nations to pieces like pottery.
- **Sardis** (Rev 3:1-6) two classes of people are further developed: Those (apparent majority) who appear alive but are dead, vs, the few (v4) who have not soiled their clothes.  The faithful overcomers are offered five rewards: *will walk with me [Jesus], *will be dressed in white, *will not erase name from book of life, *will acknowledge before the Father, *will acknowledge before angels.

Thus, Sardis simply continues the theme of two groups in some of these churches - the unfaithful vs the faithful remnant. This group is mentioned again in Rev 12:17.

Comment: I've created a follow-on question below if you'd like review https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/41396/erased-from-the-book-of-life